# Changing variable inside fetch URL returns undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have a server running on http://localhost:3000/
I have this JS:

```
let productCode = 'example-code55';

const fetchData = async  (productCode) => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/${productCode}`);
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data);
  }

fetchData();
```

but when i run it, it tries to fetch from http://localhost:3000/undefined...
im still pretty new to JS and everything else, and feel like i've sorta fell into the deep end here.

Comment: `productCode` is a function parameter, but you're calling the function with no arguments.

Comment: If you want to use the global variable, it should be `() =>`

Comment: But global variable are generally bad, so you should call `fetchData(productCode);`

Comment: thanks! i can't believe it was this simple hah

Answer (score 0):

call function with productCode as an argument at the end. You are not passing any argument.

```
fetchData(productCode);
```

Comment: Wow can't believe i missed that. Thanks a bunch!